# I need to differentiate methods that have the same signature in java

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, overloading, signature

i have many similar methods like this

```
delete(String ProfilePrimaryKey)
delete(String PostPrimaryKey)
delete(String CommentPrimaryKey)
```

they all access the database in a different way and call for a different SQL function, I don't know how to differentiate them, to keep the same name for the method

can I do something like?

```
public void delete(Profile<String> ProfilePrimaryKey);
Public void delete(Post<String> PostPrimaryKey);
public void delete(Comment<String> CommentPrimaryKey);
```

that probably didn't make sense, at all. it was just to show how I need some way of having 3 methods that all have String as argument but some different types of string, thank you for you help

Comment: I'd say that these methods should be in separate classes

Comment: You would be well served to create distinct types for these different kinds of key anyway, to avoid passing the wrong type. Then you could simply use overloading.

Comment: can I create different types of Strings? like they are all string but I call them differently

Comment: to be more specific. imagine if I am looking for a Profile in my database. I do not know yet my profile ( and that's why I am looking for it) so I can't really make an object based on my information. I only know for now which my primary key is for it. after I find the profile in my database I can create an object out of it.

Comment: Use an interface with different implementations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern